# If $R$ is an integral domain and $M=\langle m_1, \dots, m_k \rangle$ is an $R$-module, then the rank of $M$ is less than or equal to $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules

I'm supposed to use the fact that if $A \in M_{m,n}(R)$ with $m<n$, then the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. This is true since $A$ represents a map $f: R^n \to R^m$ and the columns of $A$ span the image of $f$. Thus, the number of columns is greater than the rank of $R^n$, which is $n$.

Now, if $M=\langle m_1, \dots, m_k \rangle$, then there is an epimorphism $R^k \to M$.

How could we continue using the above exercise?

Comment: What is the definition of the rank of a module? You can't solve this problem without trying to work towards that.

Comment: @Arthur The rank of a module is the cardinality of a maximal linearly independent set in $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M=\langle m_1,\ldots,m_k\rangle$, then we can write any $m\in M$ as $$m=a_1m_1+\cdots+a_km_k$$ Suppose we have a set $n_1,\ldots,n_{l}\in M$ with $l>k$, and let $n_i=a_{i,1}m_1+\cdots+a_{i,k}m_k$. Then we have a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}&\cdots&a_{l,1}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\a_{1,k} & \cdots & a_{l,k}\end{pmatrix}$$ Now, since we have more columns than rows, we must have a dependence, say $$b_1\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}\\\vdots\\a_{1,k}\end{pmatrix}+\cdots+b_l\begin{pmatrix}a_{l,1}\\\vdots\\a_{l,k}\end{pmatrix}=0$$ Then $$b_1n_1+\cdots+b_ln_l=0$$ and so the $n_i$ cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: Wow, it's simple. I guess I was overthinking it. Thanks.

Comment: Does that matrix represent the map $R^l \to R^k$ where $n_i \mapsto n_i$?

Comment: The $n_i$ are elements of $M$ so we can't talk about what happens to them in a map from $R^l\to R^k$. However, if we call the matrix $A$, and set $v_i=(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)^T\in R^l$, where the $1$ is in the $i$th position (and the $T$ denotes transpose), then $Av_i$ gives us the coefficients of $n_i$ with respect to $m_1,\ldots,m_k$, since $A$ is just the matrix of the coefficients of the $n_i$, and multiplication with $v_i$ will extract the $i$th column.

Comment: Can we take $N=\{n_1, \dots, n_l\}\subset M$ and form $R^l$ with $N$ as a basis? Then viewing $n_i \in R^l$, we can map $n_i \in R^l$ to $n_i=a_{i,1}m_1+\cdots+a_{i,k}m_k \in R^k$?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, we can't take N to be a basis of $R^l$ because $n_i\notin R^l$. The coefficients of each $n_i$ with respect to the generators $m_j$ of $M$ form columns which belong to $R^k$ since each have $k$ elements. What does happen is that our matrix $A$ sends the $i$th standard basis vector of $R^l$ to the column of coefficients of $n_i$ in $R^k$. Think of $a_{i,1},\ldots,a_{i,k}$ as the "coordinates" of $n_i$ with respect to our generating set $m_1,\ldots,m_k$ of $M$.

Comment: (We can't in general even call the $m_i$ a basis of $M$ since they aren't necessarily independent, and many modules do not have bases)

Comment: If we let $w_i\in R^k$ be the column of coefficients of $n_i$, and let $e_1,\ldots,e_l$ be the standard basis vectors of $R^l$, our matrix $A$ defines a map $R^l\to R^k$ sending $e_i\mapsto w_i$. Since $l>k$ this must have a non-trivial kernel (by say the Rank-Nullity Theorem, or because row rank=column rank etc...), so we have some $(b_1,\ldots,b_l)\in\ker(A)$, so $b_1w_1+\cdots+b_lw_l=0$ by linearity. This gives us a linear dependence on the "coordinates" of the $n_i$, and so on the $n_i$ themselves as shown in the final sum of the answer